# Configure Mac network traffic to go through Cisco Anywhere Connect VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, macos-sierra

I looked at the Cisco route details and it said:

```
Non-secured Routes (IPv4)
0.0.0.0/0

Secured Routes (IPv4)
10.x.x.x./24
172.x.x.x/24
```

Seem that only certain routes are protected. However, I occasionally work at public coffee shop and use their Wifi. How do I configure my Mac OSX Sierra to secure all routes via Cisco Anywhere Connect VPN ?

Comment: How did you configure the secure route?

Comment: @Ramhound : the secured routes configuration was done by our network admins. Is it possible to do it through VPN clients or on my local machine? I heard about Tunnelblick and wonder if I can do the same for Cisco VPN

Comment: You don't have the permissions to do what you need to do.